# How to change @DrawableRes parameter to Drawable in @Compose function?

Tags: android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, composable

Picture function draws picture out of resource id; like `R.drawable.icon`.

```
   @Composable
    fun Picture(@DrawableRes resId: Int, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
        val rectModifier = loadVectorResource(resId).resource.resource
                ?.let { asset ->
                    modifier.paint(
                            painter = VectorPainter(asset)
                    )
                }
                ?: modifier
        Box(modifier = rectModifier)
    }
```

How can I change this, so it takes a `Drawable` argument instead of an `@DrawableRes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your scenario, to which you need `Drawable` instead of the given API.

But we can achieve using the following way. `Modifier.paint` need just a `Painter` Object, Painter we can create using both `ImagePainter` and `VectorPainter`.

In our case, we want to use Drawable, so we can use `ImagePainter` and its need `ImageAsset`, so we can use `Bitmap` to create `ImageAsset`.

So the final result will be like:

```
@Composable
fun Picture(@DrawableRes resId: Int, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val resources = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(ContextAmbient.current.resources, resId, null)
    resources?.let {
        Picture(drawable = it, modifier = modifier)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Picture(drawable: Drawable, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.paint(
            ImagePainter(
                drawable.toBitmap().asImageAsset()
            )
        )
    )
}
```